# Weird Flexbox Behaviour in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

So I'm quite new to flexbox and I'm by far a real front-end developer. I'm working on a WordPress theme for an upcoming side project and currently I'm doing the HTML part.

I'm using flexbox for pretty much everything, and I'm having some issues with some weird flexbox behaviour.

If you go to http://hatch.tips/preview and check it in Chrome, everything seems to be alright. Mozilla is also fine except a weird border to the right of the compacted logo (resize browser).

On Safari, things go pretty haywire, so you should check that up.

I'd highly appreciate any help. First of all you might notice that I haven't used any prefixes for my code yet, but since Safari renders some of the flexbox stuff, I assumed that might not be the actual problem.

Comment: I am constantly reminded to never assume.  Autoprefixer is your friend http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: @Paulie_D I understand what you're saying, but instead of throwing all my code plus screenshots in the thread, making it huge, I'd rather share a link to the wip files so devs can see for themselves.

Comment: Nope. Links to code are of no use either, Demos of actual code ARE.

Comment: @Michael_B That link is quite helpful. I'll look into that and see if I can troubleshoot this, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox is still "fairly new" so I recommend using the prefixers. It fix most of the bugs, especially in IE for instance.

See: http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I prefixed my code, still the problem occurs I'm afraid.